# Python filtering list of objects by distinct attribute

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

I have a list of objects with multiple attributes. I want to filter the list based on one attribute of the object (country_code), i.e.

Current list

```
elems = [{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'ROM', 'country_desc': 'Romania', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'ROM', 'country_desc':'Romania', 'event_number': '3200'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'ROM', 'country_desc': 'Romania', 'event_number': '4000'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'SVN', 'country_desc': 'Slovenia', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'NLD', 'country_desc':'Netherlands', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'BEL', 'country_desc':'Belgium', 'event_number': '6880'}]
```

Desired list

```
elems = [{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'ROM', 'country_desc': 'Romania', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'SVN', 'country_desc': 'Slovenia', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'NLD', 'country_desc': 'Netherlands', 'event_number': '6880'}, 
{'region_code': 'EUD', 'country_code': 'BEL', 'country_desc': 'Belgium', 'event_number': '6880'}]
```

I can achieve this by creating a dictionary and a for-loop, but I feel like there's an easier way in python using the filter() or reduce() functions, I just can't figure out how.

**Can anyone simplify the below code using in-built python functions? Performance is a big factor because the real data will be substantial.**

Working code:

```
unique = {}
for elem in elems:
  if elem['country_code'] not in unique.keys():
     unique[elem['country_code']] = elem

print(unique.values())
```

Worth noting I have also tried the code below, but it performs worse than the current working code:

```
unique = []
for elem in elems:
    if not any(u['country_code'] == elem['country_code'] for u in unique):
        unique.append(elem)
```

Comment: I think your first working code, with the dict, is pretty optimal. Maybe use `collections.OrderedDict` so the order is the same as in the list, if that's important. Also, no need to call `.keys()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your first approach is already pretty close to being optimal. Dictionary lookup is fast (just as fast as in a `set`) and the loop is easy to understand, even though a bit lengthy (by Python standards), but you should not sacrifice readability for brevity.

You can, however, shave off one line using `setdefault`, and you might want to use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) so that the elements in the resulting list are in their orginal order. Also, note that in Python 3, `unique.values()` is not a list but a view on the dict.

```
unique = collections.OrderedDict()
for elem in elems:
    unique.setdefault(elem["country_code"], elem)
```

If you really, *really* want to use `reduce`, you can use the empty dict as an initializer and then use `d.setdefault(k,v) and d` to set the value (if not present) and return the modified dict.

```
unique = reduce(lambda unique, elem: unique.setdefault(elem["country_code"], elem) and unique,
                elems, collections.OrderedDict())
```

I would just use the loop, though.

Comment: setdefault where have you been all my life?? This works well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that your approach is just fine. It would be slightly better to check `elem['country_code'] not in unique` instead of `elem['country_code'] not in unique.keys()`.

However, here is another way to do it with a list comprehension:

```
visited = set()
res = [e for e in elems
        if e['country_code'] not in visited
        and not visited.add(e['country_code'])]
```

The last bit abuses the fact that `not None == True` and `list.add` returns `None`.

Comment: thanks @Yakym - this is quick and clean. I'm going to go with tobias_k's answer because it's less code change but the performance is the same. Thanks!